# bins must increase monotonically

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I just want to draw Matplotlib histograms from skimage.exposure but I get a `ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.` The original image comes from [here](http://python-prepa.github.io/_images/coins_black_small.jpg) and here my code:

```
from skimage import io, exposure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = io.imread('img/coins_black_small.jpg', as_grey=True)
hist,bins=exposure.histogram(img)

plt.hist(bins,hist)
```

> ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.

But the same error arises when I sort the bins values:

```
import numpy as np
sorted_bins = np.sort(bins)
plt.hist(sorted_bins,hist)
```

> ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.

I finally tried to check the bins values, but they seem sorted in my opinion (any advice for this kind of test would appreciated also):

```
if any(bins[:-1] >= bins[1:]):
    print "bim"
```

No output from this.

Any suggestion on what happens?
I'm trying to learn Python, so be indulgent please. Here my install (on Linux Mint):

- Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
- Jupyter 4.2.1

Comment: I've most often seen this when there are NaN's in the array. What does `any(np.isnan(img))` return?

Comment: @bnaecker > ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Matplotlib `hist` accept data as first argument, not already binned counts. Use matplotlib `bar` to plot it. Note that unlike numpy `histogram`, skimage `exposure.histogram` returns the centers of bins.

```
width = bins[1] - bins[0]
plt.bar(bins, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct solution is:

> All bin values must be whole numbers, no decimals! You can use round()
> function.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `plt.hist` is `plt.hist(data, bins, ...)`. So you are trying to plug the already computed histogram as bins into the matplotlib `hist` function. The histogram is of course not sorted and therefore the "bins must increase monotonically"-error is thrown.

While you could of course use `plt.hist(hist, bins)`, it's questionable if histogramming a histogram is of any use. I would guess that you want to simply plot the result of the first histogramming.

Using a bar chart would make sense for this purpose:

```
hist,bins=numpy.histogram(img)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width=(bins[-1]-bins[-2]), align="edge")
```

Comment: Damn, indeed. And thank you for your remark on the use of `plt.hist` vs `plt.bar`.

Comment: But are you sure about `plt.bar(bins[:-1],...)`? (it returns an error on > incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 255 or scalar) Shouldn't it be `plt.bar(bins,...)`?

Comment: You can of course try it out. I am sure that if you were using `hist, bins = numpy.histogram` you would need to use `plt.bar(bins[:-1],...)`, because `bins` denotes the edges and thus is one larger than `hist`. Now, what I don't know is if `skimage.exposure.histogram` is different from that. As you get an error, it seems so. I updated the answer to use numpy.