# Plotting 2D Histogram with customize bins values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following pandas dataframe having thousands of rows.

[image]

I want to plot a 2D histogram based on "mains:active_power" and "mains:reactive_power".
I used matplotlib library for plotting the 2D histogram in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.subplots(figsize =(10, 7)) 
plt.hist2d(df["mains:active_power"], df["mains:reactive_power"]) 
plt.title("Simple 2D Histogram")  
plt.show()
```

It plots successfully, but I want to customize the bin values for both x_bin and y_bin.
I used following command for it:

```
plt.hist2d(df["mains:active_power"], df["mains:reactive_power"], bins =[x_bins, y_bins]).
```

x_bins, y_bins are the NumPy array containing the value of the bin. Also, the size of x_bins, y_bins equals the length of dataframe (df)

Whenever I run this, I got an error:

**ValueError: `bins[0]` must be monotonically increasing, when an array**

How to troubleshoot this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi could you please tell everyone how you solved it or accept the answer, for people in the future to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why  the size of `x_bins, y_bins` equals the length of the dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that plt.bar will be a much better choice.

```
width = bins[1] - bins[0]
plt.bar(bins, hist, align="edge", width=width)
plt.show()
```

Hope I could help. The same kind of question has been asked here for further reference.
[bins must increase monotonically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166763/bins-must-increase-monotonically)